# What am I doing wrong with discontinuous ODEs and `integrate.odeint`?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I have two discontinuous ODEs and `odeint` works as expected for one but not the other.

```
c_func = interp1d(k, c)
c_s_func = interp1d(k,np.concatenate((c_l_75[k<k_c],c[k>=k_c])))

def kdot(k_val,t):
    return f(k_val)-c_func(k_val)
def kdot_s(k_val,t):
    return f(k_val)-c_s_func(k_val)
```

The functions `c_func` and `c_s_func` are linear interpolations of numerically computed points and the `f` function is discontinuous at a point `k_c`. Plots of `kdot` and `kdot_s` are:

[image: kdots]

I call `odeint` as follows:

```
t = np.linspace(0,75,101)
k0 = .2
khat = odeint(kdot, k0, t)
khat_s = odeint(kdot_s, k0, t)
```

but the solution for `khat_s` becomes completely flat when it reaches the discontinuity as `k_c`:

[image: solved odes]

I expected the `khat_s` line to look like the `khat` line does upon reaching `k_c`.  I.e., the portion of the blue line above the dashed line shifted to the right to meet the the point where the orange line met the dashed line.  Instead the dashed line becomes flat at that point.

Comment: Question: *"What am I doing wrong with discontinuous ODEs and `integrate.odeint`?"*   Answer: You are using `integrate.odeint` to solve a discontinuous ODE. 

Comment: Longer answer: Like *many* ODE solvers, the LSODA code that `odeint` wraps is based on the assumption that the formulas for the derivatives are smooth.  A discontinuity breaks that assumption.    Whether or not the solver will work in that case is uncertain. The adaptive algorithm in the solver might fail to converge near the discontinuity.  Or it might work, but it might take an excessive amount of very small steps as it tries to bring the estimated local error under control.  Or it might return garbage.

Comment: Thank you!  Looking at the points for `khat_s` I see that it gets close to `k_c` but never actually reaches it.  I will play around with solving the ODE a second time, forcing the new starting point to be `k_c`.